# Прямая речь внутри авторских слов. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Когда пришёл посланный слуга и спросил: "Готова ли посылка?" (,) - ему ответили: "Уже как два дня..."

Вопрос в том, надо ли после первой реплики ставить запятую? По Розенталю, "*запятая и тире ставятся между двумя репликами разных лиц, находящихся внутри авторских слова*". Но смущает в таком случае количество подряд идущих знаков (?", -)

Ещё вопрос, можно ли здесь не ставить запятую на том основании, что первая реплика входит в придаточную часть, а тире - знак, который разделяет части сложноподчинённого предложения:
**(Когда)** **- [ответили]** ?

И ещё - маленькое уточнение по поводу правила Розенталя. Подпадает ли приведённое выше предложение под это правило или же последнее (правило) для тех случаев, когда две реплики разных лиц в предложении соседствуют (идут одна за другой), как и приводится у Розенталя: *Когда приказчик говорил: "Хорошо бы, барин, то и то сделать", - "Да, недурно", - отвечал он обыкновенно.* И опять: будет ли ставиться здесь запятая перед тире в том случае, если последняя реплика заканчивается вопросом или восклицательным знаком: *Когда приказчик говорил: "Хорошо бы, барин, то и то сделать!" (,) - "Да, недурно", - отвечал он обыкновенно.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У того же Розенталя приведены примеры для Вашего случая (§ 50):

Если прямая речь находится внутри авторских слов, то перед ней ставится двоеточие, а после нее — запятая, тире или запятая и тире (по условиям контекста):
а) *Отец Василий поднял брови и курил, пуская дым из носа, потом сказал:  «Да, так вот как»,  вздохнул, помолчал и ушёл (А.Т.)* — запятая разделяет однородные сказуемые сказал и вздохнул, между которыми находится прямая речь; *…Софья Карловна ещё раз поцеловала Маню и, сказав ей:  «Поди, гуляй, моя крошка»,  сама поплелась за свои ширмы (Леск.)* — запятая закрывает деепричастный оборот, в состав которого включена прямая речь; *Ко мне подходит Борис, говорит: «Хорошо сбил, замечательно»,  но глаза его блестят, полные зависти (Куд.)* — запятая разделяет части сложносочиненного предложения, связанные противительным союзом но; *Приехав на дачу в большой компании… брат вдруг говорил: «Мишка, пойдём на биллиард»,  и они, запершись, играли по три часа на биллиарде (Сим.)* — запятая перед союзом и в сложносочиненном предложении;
б) *…Она сказала:  «Нынче, говорят, в университете уже мало занимаются науками» — и подозвала свою собачку Сюзетку (Л.Т.)* — тире перед союзом и при однородных сказуемых; *Тут уж он и совсем обомлел:  «Ваше благородие, батюшка барин, да как вы… да стою ли я…» — и заплакал вдруг (Дост.)* — тире после многоточия, которым заканчивается прямая речь; ***На вопрос мой:  «Жив ли старый смотритель?»  — никто не мог дать мне удовлетворительного ответа (П.)* — тире после вопросительного знака, которым заканчивается прямая речь; *И только когда он шептал:  «Мама! Мама!»  — ему становилось как будто легче (Ч.)* — тире после восклицательного знака, которым заканчивается прямая речь**; *Не говорить же: «Эй, собака!» или «Эй, кошка!»*  — две реплики, разделенные неповторяющимся союзом или.

Запятая ставится при отсутствии других знаков. И вопросительный/восклицательный знак, и запятая одновременно не ставятся. Поэтому в Вашем случае достаточно тире.
Также в Вашем предложении реплики разделены авторскими словами, а не следуют друг за другом, как в приведённом примере из Розенталя. Для Вашего случая — пункт б.